# Add multiple TextView to ViewfFlipper in Manifest?

Tags: android, google-glass, viewflipper

I am attempting to add multiple TextView to a ViewFlipper through the Manifest.

This is what I have done:

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/phrase_flipper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.abc.utils.AutoResizeTextView
        android:id="@+id/instruction_context"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="This Is Screen 1"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        />

    <com.abc.utils.AutoResizeTextView
        android:id="@+id/phrase_primary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height= "190dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        />
</ViewFlipper>
```

However, when doing so, it is interpreted as "instruction_context" being shown on even views and phrase_primary on odd views.

Is there a way around that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI that's not a manifest, it is just an xml resource file.

Try containing your TextViews in a ViewGroup, which ViewFlipper should hopefully treat as a single View:

```
<ViewFlipper
android:id="@+id/phrase_flipper"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<com.abc.utils.AutoResizeTextView
    android:id="@+id/instruction_context"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="This Is Screen 1"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    />

<com.abc.utils.AutoResizeTextView
    android:id="@+id/phrase_primary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height= "190dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    />

</LinearLayout>
</ViewFlipper>
```

Comment: Thanks it made it. Interestingly, the XML interpreter in Eclipse mentions that LinearLayout or its ViewFlipper parent is useless.